# Is there a way to unnest an array in one select statement?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, unnest

I have the following:

```
CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    IssueID, CompanyName, Customer.ID FROM
 ( SELECT
    IssueID,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CompanyName,'[a-zA-Z]{3,4}[0-9]{3,4}') AS CompanyName
  FROM 
    `DWH.website` Website
  LEFT JOIN  `DWH.issues` AS Issue ON DWH.IssueID = Issue.ID) AS BASE

CROSS JOIN UNNEST (CompanyName) AS CompanyName
LEFT JOIN 
  DWH.Customer ON  CompanyName = Customer.CompanyName
)
```

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of writing this, specifically if there is a way to UNNEST in one Select Statement.

Example of Desired Output

| IssueID | CompanyName | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18677 | Google | 19435 |
| 18677 | Logitech | 22345 |
| 34564 | Target | 76845 |

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a part of a larger query (because some tables like `DWH` and `Customer` are missing), but, assuming that it works, you can try this:

```
CTE AS (
  SELECT IssueID, CompanyName, Customer.ID 
  FROM `DWH.website` Website
  LEFT JOIN `DWH.issues` AS Issue ON DWH.IssueID = Issue.ID
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CompanyName,'[a-zA-Z]{3,4}[0-9]{3,4}')) AS CompanyName
  LEFT JOIN DWH.Customer ON CompanyName = Customer.CompanyName
)
```